# Convert NodeList to array

Tags: javascript, prototype, internet-explorer-8, nodelist

I'm having a hard time converting a `NodeList` to an array in IE 8.  The following works perfectly in Chrome, but in IE 8 `toArray()` is not recognized as valid:

```
NodeList.prototype.toArray = function() {
    var a = [];

    for (var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; i++) {
        a[i] = this[i];
    }

    return a;
}

document.all.tags("div").toArray();
```

I tried adding a prototype function to an array just to check my sanity and it works correctly.  That makes me think IE 8 doesn't actually return a `NodeList`?  Here's a full example:

http://jsfiddle.net/e4RbH/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is no current standard that says that `NodeList` has to be a visible and alterable constructor function, or that if there is a constructor function visible as `NodeList` that it will be used as the return type of all NodeList-returning methods. (After all, a `childNodes` NodeList and a `getElementsByTagName` NodeList do very different things.) Prototyping onto the native JS objects is specified by the ECMAScript standard and is reliable; prototyping onto DOM Nodes and other objects not defined by the language standard is unreliable and should be avoided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, don't use `document.all` -- it's non-standard and deprecated. Use [`document.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) to get the DIV elements in your case.

Second, don't extend DOM objects such as `NodeList` -- built-in objects are a very strange breed and are not required to behave like any other objects that you generally work with. See this article for an in-depth explanation of this: [What's wrong with extending the DOM](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/).

Comment: I was using `getElementByTagName`, but switched to `document.all` during testing.  This was part of a bigger problem and I tried to simplify it down.  The real problem ended up being an extension method to `Array` which was improperly implemented and affected other code.

Comment: Good comments but doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 11):

If you're looking for a modern answer using ES6:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('div');
nodes = Array.from(nodes);
```

Comment: You could also use spread operator `const array = [...nodes]`

Answer (score 5):

Old question, but here is a tried & true method:

```
var nodes=document.querySelectorAll("div"); //  returns a node list
nodes=Array.prototype.slice.call(nodes);    //  copies to an array
```

Explanation

- `document.querySelectorAll` uses a CSS-style selector to find elements and returns a node list. It works as of IE 8.
- The `slice` method copies a portion of an array-like collection (in this case all of it) into a new array.
- `call` allows you to borrow a method from one object to use on another

To find the node list you could also have used `document.getElementsByTagName(), but this one is more flexible.

Comment: You can't call slice on a nodeList in IE8 :\

Answer (score 1):

IE doesn't support `NodeList` in the standard way. This is why you should roll your own namespace and NOT extend browser core objects.

You can do `alert( typeof window.NodeList )` and see if it's undefined or not.

Comment: In Chrome it's `function`, in IE 8 it's `object`, not `undefined`.  Either way, this was debugging some old code which I have now refactored into a namespace I already had.

Comment: You must have a newer version of IE8 'cause mine is undefined.