# Convert <td> elements into array with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

My goal is to create one array and later on insert some data using `.unshift` method.

I want an array to contain `td` elements only and be created using JavaScript instead of jQuery. Is it possible?

Here's my table :

```
<table id="scorestable">
    <tr>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Score</th>
        <th>Score</th>
        <th>Type</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    .....
```

Comment: Is it possible? That's your question?

Comment: No, because you haven't tried anything.

Answer (score 1):

simply use:

```
var elements = document.getElementById("scorestable").getElementsByTagName('td');
```

then you will have: `elements[0]` , `elements[1]` and etc..

Comment: That's not an array, so it won't have `unshift`. It will live-update, but we don't know that's what the OP wants.

Comment: Array like objects FTW!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557817/convert-nodelist-to-array?s=1|3.2666 for how to convert the `NodeList` to an array.

Comment: As @adil.hilmi's answer shows, you only need to add `Array.prototype.slice.call(<SomeNodeList>);` to get an `Array` from a `NodeList`

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="scorestable">
  <tr>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Score</th>
    <th>Score</th>
    <th>Type</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>33</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
  window.onload = function(e) {
    var arrayResult = [];
    var tdList = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById("scorestable").getElementsByTagName('td'));
    tdList.forEach(function logArrayElements(element, index, array) {
      if (element.innerText && element.innerText != "undefined") {
        arrayResult.unshift(element.innerText);
      }
    });
    console.log(arrayResult);
  }

</script>
```