# Javascript , How can I get all values from tag attributes into an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually, I need two arrays, from two attributes, "id_play" and "orden_play".

I share my code here:

```js
let id_play = [];
let orden_play = [];

id_play = $("#listaOrdenable").children().attr('id_play');
orden_play = $("#listaOrdenable").children().attr('orden_play');
```

```html
<ul id="listaOrdenable" class="s1">
  <li orden_play="0" id_play="47"><img src="uploads/meade.jpg"  width="40" heigth="40">1</li>
  <li orden_play="1" id_play="49"><img src="uploads/videoIcon.png"  width="40" heigth="40">2</li>
  <li orden_play="2" id_play="50"><img src="uploads/RARA.jpg"  width="40" heigth="40">3</li>
  <li orden_play="3" id_play="51"><img src="uploads/videoIcon.png"  width="40" heigth="40">4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You should be careful about adding arbitrary custom attributes to your HTML documents as it makes them invalid although they will render just fine in most of the cases I am aware of. See [Can I add custom attribute to HTML tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735230/can-i-add-custom-attribute-to-html-tag)

Comment: It seems bad design to want to store attributes that relate to each other in different arrays. I suppose you will then use the index in those arrays to know which belongs with which. It would be better if you would create *one* array, of objects, where each object has those two properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let id_play = [];
let orden_play = [];

const children = $("#listaOrdenable").children().map((childId, child) => child.attributes);
const getAttrFromChild = (attr) => children.get().map(child => child[attr].value);

id_play = getAttrFromChild("id_play")
orden_play = getAttrFromChild("orden_play")

console.log(id_play, orden_play)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution:

```
id_play = []
orden_play = []

$("#listaOrdenable").children('li').each(function(){
    id_play.push(this.getAttribute('id_play'));
    id_play.push(this.getAttribute('orden_play'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using jQuerys $.each to access each attribute in the list. I've added 2 loops at the end of the code for verification. You can get rid of them if you don't need it

```
let id_play = [];
let orden_play =[];

$.each($('#listaOrdenable').children(), function(i,v){
    id_play.push($(this).attr('id_play'));
    orden_play.push($(this).attr('orden_play'));
});

//You can remove these two loops if you don't need them
for(var i in id_play) {
    console.log(id_play[i]);
}
for(var x in orden_play) {
    console.log(orden_play[x]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a plain javascript solution:

```
const arr1 = [].map.call(document.getElementById('listaOrdenable').querySelectorAll('li'), li => li.getAttribute('orden_play'))

const arr2 = [].map.call(document.getElementById('listaOrdenable').querySelectorAll('li'), li => li.getAttribute('id_play'))
```

What I am basically doing is selecting all the `li` nodes from the `ul` and I map over them and grab the desired attribute. The purpose of `[].map.call` is that `querySelectorAll()` returns a `NodeList` which is an Array like structure. It doesn't have all the array functions, so the `.call` approach I used is a way of using array functions on array like structures.

I haven't tested it in jQuery, but I presume that the `.children()` function will return what `querySelectorAll()` returns in my example.

Hope this helps, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest possible pure JS solution:

```
let id_play = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("li[id_play]"));
let orden_play = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("li[orden_play]"));
```

This approach is using [David Walsh's proposal](https://davidwalsh.name/nodelist-array) to convert NodeList to Array.
You can also use `Array.from()`. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46631477/8815185).

But, I have to add one more. This is by far the most elegant way, using ES6 [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

**ES6 solution:**

```
let id_play = [...(document.querySelectorAll("li[id_play]"))];
let orden_play = [...(document.querySelectorAll("li[orden_play]"))];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JQuery each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) on all the children of element `listaOrdenable`, and then `push` the attributes you are looking for on the related arrays. Check the next example:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var id_play = [];
    var orden_play = [];

    $("#listaOrdenable").children().each(function()
    {
        id_play.push($(this).attr("id_play"));
        orden_play.push($(this).attr("orden_play"));
    });
    
    console.log(id_play);
    console.log(orden_play);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="listaOrdenable" class="s1">
  <li orden_play="0" id_play="47"><img src="uploads/meade.jpg"  width="40" heigth="40">1</li>
  <li orden_play="1" id_play="49"><img src="uploads/videoIcon.png"  width="40" heigth="40">2</li>
  <li orden_play="2" id_play="50"><img src="uploads/RARA.jpg"  width="40" heigth="40">3</li>
  <li orden_play="3" id_play="51"><img src="uploads/videoIcon.png"  width="40" heigth="40">4</li>
</ul>
```

In the case, you want to save the elements as integer numbers, you have to use the next code:

```
id_play.push(Number($(this).attr("id_play")));
orden_play.push(Number($(this).attr("orden_play")));
```

Answer (score 0):

id_play = []
orden_play = []

$("#listaOrdenable li").each(function() {
    `id_play.push($(this).attr('id_play'));`
    `id_play.push($(this).attr('orden_play'));`
});